# Spring Security: You cannot use a spring-security-2.0.xsd or spring-security-3.0.xsd or spring-security-3.1.xsd schema with Spring Security 3.2

Tags: spring, gradle, spring-security, spring-boot, build.gradle

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8916993/spring-security3-you-cannot-use-a-spring-security-2-0-xsd-schema) answer but it is not helping me. I have the schema definition in the xml file as:

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd">
```

And in the build.gradle file, the specification of the dependencies is as:

```
compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-config', version: spring_security_version
compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-data', version: spring_security_version
compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-web', version: spring_security_version
compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-messaging', version: spring_security_version
compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-acl', version: spring_security_version
```

As you can see, the version of the Spring Security dependencies is mentioned as spring_security_version. I am not sure how to represent the version in the schema definition of the xml file.

Comment: download jars that are all of the same version number and the problem will be resolved

Comment: What is the value of spirng_security_version its value some where must be defined.In the xml file you just need to point it to the correct version of xsd which is the value of spring _security_version

Comment: It is recommended to use version less schemas so `spring-security.xsd` instead of `spring-security-3.2.xsd` that way you always use the proper schema. That goes for plain xsd versions as well.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys! All of your answers make sense in this regard so I am confused which one to pick.

@M.Deinum: Can you please post as answer so I can accept as I find it more convenient.